# Build Failed No Reason Stated

Tags: ios, build

When I build my application in the simulator mode, it works fine. But when I try and build it for the active target to be my iOS device I get a build failed with no explanation as to why?

Does anyone know what I need to do, it was working yesterday I have all my certificates and everything I don't understand.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more information if you want an answer.  Have you looked at the console window, have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check your bundle identifier. I accidentally put a * in there and got the Build Failed with no reason.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had not linked a framework which I was using in the project.

Comment: Yep, I had my own "framework", not a dylib, was linking to it in my filesystem, and I removed it, and the header search paths etc. Somehow, it came back in the frameworks section, but of course the info.plist still didn't point to it so... didn't work. Should have told me a message thought...

Answer (score 0):

With this information, I can just guess.

I was running in a similar problem and my problem was the bundle identifier in the `Info.plist`. I had a whitespace in the name and that's why it failed with `"No Issues"`.

My current Bundle identifier is: `com.mycompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`.
I think the `"rfc1034identifier"` makes everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Resurces added into the project such as images,textfiles which was copied into Xcode project ,if the copied file's original source is deleted this can also have similar issue, i faced the same.

> > Note:Only the files copied as, Copy items into destination group folders's Unchecked while adding the file to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In *my* case, I had a syntax error which did now show up in the panel. I was compiling within a workspace that contained two projects. When I opened both of them individually, the syntax error showed up and I could fix it!